# CakePHP While-loop inside another loop

Tags: cakephp, while-loop

Since I'm in need of my navigation buttons I've placed the following code inside my AppController since i need it on every page.

```
// app/Controller/AppController.php
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $uses = array('Categorie');

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        $parents = $this->Categorie->find('all', array('conditions' => array('cat_parent' => 0)));
        $childs = $this->Categorie->find('threaded', array('conditions' => array('cat_parent' => $parents['Categorie']['cat_id'])));

        echo '<pre>'.var_dump($parents).'</pre>';
    }
}
```

I don't think this is the good way too accomplish what I want.. how can i do a while inside a while with the CakePHP Framework.

Kind Regards,

Jordy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `while` loop in this case, you could just find the categories where  `cat_parent` is not zero:

```
$childs = $this->Categorie->find('threaded', array(
    'conditions' => 'cat_parent != 0'
));
```

Comment: Well I've got 2 parents. I need to match the childrens with the parent. If i'll use your method I've got too use multiple queries.

Comment: Are you using `TreeBehavior`? You could use `find('threaded')` on the first call (`$parents = ...`)  to get the whole tree below each parent.

Comment: I'm reading something about $this->data->generatetreelist(); is this useful?

Comment: Yes, it's useful, but the array returned will only have the ID's (as keys), and the value of one field of your choice as values. To get all fields, you should look into [`find('threaded')`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1023/find-threaded)

Comment: Thanks for help. It it possible to contact you later? My day at work is over so tomorrow another start.

Comment: Not sure if I'll be here tomorrow at this time, but you can try!

Comment: Problem solved, if i change the db tablenames to id + parent_id Cake will generate the tree automaticly with $this>Categorie->find('threaded'); thats it! Thank you helping me on good path.